# Identify if a PostgreSQL dump was created using parallel dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, postgresql-13

I am dumping a large database using the -j (--jobs) option as so:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -Fd -j 5 "openiam" -f "/home/pdump"
```

How do I identify this dump was created using the -j option? I want to store dump metadata along with the dump. Is there some `pg_restore` option?

Version: PostgreSQL 13 and OS: RHEL 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as the value of `-j` option is not part of the metadata of the dump. The information is also not needed as that parameter does not change the structure, size or layout of the dump so it's irrelevant when restoring the dump.

When restoring the dump there is no need to know how many jobs where used to create the dump.

If you really need to store this for some other purpose, then you will need to adjust your backup script to store it somewhere.